# how to write mysql error and out log with timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

How to write the `error.log` file and `out.log` file with timestamp for each line.??

```
mysqlcheck -u root -pPASS --check --quick --auto-repair test  >> /var/log/sample/out.log 2>>/var/log/sample/error.log
```

I want the timestamp to write for each error line and each output line.How to do it the above line?